# Install Ubuntu 14.04 while display is distorted

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, ati, display

I'm currently trying to install ver. 14.04 booting off of a USB, however my display is distorted. I believe I need to install the correct video card drivers, but how can I do that if I can't get Ubuntu to install? I read in another post on this board that I need to install the AMD drivers through fglrx but I don't know how I would do that if I can't really see anything and the system just freezes up as well. I have a AMD Radeon HD 6570 which I saw is fully supported through 'TURKS' (not really sure what this is).

I've tried entering `nomodeset` by pressing *tab* on the **Install Ubuntu** option at the boot menu and pressing enter, but that hasn't done anything for me. I would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Here are my *system specs*:

> MB: Gigabyte; Model 965P-DS3
>
> 300 GB SATA HD
>
> 6 GB DDR2
>
> 64 bit Windows 7
>
> 2 Processor cores

Comment: Try installing Ubuntu server edition instead. It will use a command-line based installer and won't install any graphical software. When it's done, install Gnome/KDE using the command line along side the video driver you need. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems

Comment: Alternatively to above, try setting `vga=791` after the nomodeset param. (1024*768 SVGA mode, works on most video cards) Drop a comment @fabby if this doesn't work.

Comment: Issue is gone when tried from DVD instead of USB. Voting as no-repro

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I created a live DVD and ran the installation from there versus the USB and everything worked perfect. Maybe I had dorked up the way I created the USB.